# Android App gets stuck on splash screen when launched on physical device

Tags: android

When I run the app on physical device Samsung Android 11 android Studio it launches well but hangs on the splash screen. What could be the problem?

I have uppdate the app with
AndroidX.
targetSdkVersion 30.
All the Firebase to the newest.
okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.2
butterknife:10.2.1

And still i get error, this is from the logcat and i don´t now what i means.

```
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (32604) for package com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user ----------------------------
ActivityThread          D  handleBindApplication()++ app=com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user
nstransfer.use          I  The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
ActivityThread          D  handleBindApplication() -- skipGraphicsSupport=false
ActivityThread          D  ActivityThread::handleMakeApplication() data=AppBindData{appInfo=ApplicationInfo{f6ab5a0 com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user}} appContext=android.app.ContextImpl@d864559 appContext.mOpPackageName=com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user appContext.mBasePackageName=com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user appContext.mPackageInfo=android.app.LoadedApk@722d51e data.restrictedBackupMode= false data.providers= [ContentProviderInfo{name=com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user.firebaseinitprovider className=com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider}, ContentProviderInfo{name=com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user.crashlyticsinitprovider className=com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider}, ContentProviderInfo{name=com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user.FacebookInitProvider className=com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider}, ContentProviderInfo{name=com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user.easyphotopicker.fileprovider className=pl.aprilapps.easyphotopicker.ExtendedFileProvider}, ContentProviderInfo{name=com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user.androidx-startup className=androidx.startup.InitializationProvider}, ContentProviderInfo{name=com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user.AccountKitInitialization className=com.facebook.accountkit.internal.AccountKitInitProvider}] Caller=android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication:7440 android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400:301 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage:2148 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:106 android.os.Looper.loop:246 
LoadedApk               D  LoadedApk::makeApplication() appContext=android.app.ContextImpl@9f811ff appContext.mOpPackageName=com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user appContext.mBasePackageName=com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user appContext.mPackageInfo=android.app.LoadedApk@722d51e
NetworkSecurityConfig   D  Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: true
NetworkSecurityConfig   D  Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: true
MultiDex                I  VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
MultiDex                I  Installing application
MultiDex                I  VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
FirebaseApp             I  Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
DynamiteModule          I  Considering local module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:83 and remote module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:93
DynamiteModule          I  Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite, version >= 93
DynamiteModule          V  Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
System                  W  ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
FirebaseCrashlytics     I  Initializing Crashlytics 17.2.2
FirebaseInitProvider    I  FirebaseApp initialization successful
CrashlyticsInitProvider I  CrashlyticsInitProvider skipping initialization
nstransfer.use          W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/sec/clipboard/ClipboardUIManager;->getInstance(Landroid/content/Context;)Landroid/sec/clipboard/ClipboardUIManager; (blacklist, reflection, denied)
FA                      V  App measurement collection enabled
FA                      V  App measurement enabled for app package, google app id: com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user, 1:1087590566520:android:135422ea7748317fb9bb8d
FA                      I  App measurement initialized, version: 80013
FA                      I  To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
FA                      I  To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user

FA                      D  Debug-level message logging enabled
FA                      D  Resetting session stitching token to not null
System.out              I  (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
FA                      V  Connecting to remote service
MultiDex                I  Installing application
MultiDex                I  VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
stetho                  I  Listening on @stetho_com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user_devtools_remote
System.out              I  (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
System.out              I  (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
FA                      V  Connection attempt already in progress
Fabric                  E  Settings request failed.
Answers                 E  Failed to retrieve settings
FA                      V  Connection attempt already in progress
AppCompatDelegate       D  Checking for metadata for AppLocalesMetadataHolderService : Service not found
FA                      V  onActivityCreated
DecorView               I  [INFO] isPopOver=false, config=true
DecorView               I  updateCaptionType >> DecorView@91aad0e[], isFloating=false, isApplication=true, hasWindowDecorCaption=false, hasWindowControllerCallback=true
DecorView               D  setCaptionType = 0, this = DecorView@91aad0e[]
nstransfer.use          W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
nstransfer.use          W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
Dialog                  I  mIsSamsungBasicInteraction = false, isMetaDataInActivity = false
DecorView               I  [INFO] isPopOver=false, config=false
DecorView               I  updateCaptionType >> DecorView@fb0361f[], isFloating=true, isApplication=true, hasWindowDecorCaption=false, hasWindowControllerCallback=false
DecorView               D  setCaptionType = 0, this = DecorView@fb0361f[]
KeyHash:                D  MvoK71ndTqBgOHe6h/alaUPrJVk=
FCM                     D  FCM Token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TetheringManager        I  registerTetheringEventCallback:com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user
ConnectivityManager     D  ConnectivityManager() mContext=com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user.MvpApplication@51514bd getOpPackageName()=com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user getBasePackageName()=com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user getPackageName()=com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user
LOTTIE                  W  Animation contains merge paths. Merge paths are only supported on KitKat+ and must be manually enabled by calling enableMergePathsForKitKatAndAbove().
FA                      V  Activity resumed, time: 319576950
FA                      I  Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
SensorManager           D  registerListener :: 1, ICM42605M Accelerometer, 66667, 0, com.facebook.appevents.codeless.ViewIndexingTrigger@18cf332
InputTransport          D  Input channel constructed: '1fd2ec ', fd=73
ViewRootIm...hActivity] I  setView = com.android.internal.policy.DecorView@91aad0e TM=true
FA                      V  Connection attempt already in progress
FA                      V  Connection attempt already in progress
LOTTIE                  W  Animation contains merge paths but they are disabled.
System.out              I  (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
System.out              I  (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
ViewRootIm...hActivity] D  controlInsetsForCompatibility: hideByFlags=0x1, showByFlags=0x0, flags=0x81810500, sysUiVis=0x0, matchParent=true, nonAttachedAppWindow=true
InsetsSourceConsumer    D  setRequestedVisible: visible=false, type=0, host=com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user/com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user.ui.activity.splash.SplashActivity, from=android.view.InsetsSourceConsumer.hide:236 android.view.InsetsController.collectSourceControls:1172 android.view.InsetsController.controlAnimationUnchecked:1049 android.view.InsetsController.applyAnimation:1417 android.view.InsetsController.hide:984 android.view.InsetsController.hide:967 android.view.ViewRootImpl.controlInsetsForCompatibility:2865 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:3327 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2631 android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run:9978 
SurfaceControl          I  assignNativeObject: nativeObject = 0 Surface(name=null)/@0xf86d63a / android.view.SurfaceControl.readFromParcel:1115 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.relayout:1820 android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow:9018 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:3373 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2631 android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run:9978 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run:1010 android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks:809 android.view.Choreographer.doFrame:744 android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run:995 
ViewRootIm...hActivity] I  Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2340) new=(0,83,1080,2340) req=(1080,2340)0 dur=11 res=0x7 s={true 480769073152} ch=true fn=-1
ViewRootIm...hActivity] I  [DP] dp(1) 1 android.view.ViewRootImpl.reportNextDraw:10964 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:3858 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2631 
ViewRootIm...hActivity] I  [DP] pd() Asnyc report
Gralloc4                I  mapper 4.x is not supported
Gralloc3                W  mapper 3.x is not supported
gralloc                 I  Arm Module v1.0
ViewRootIm...hActivity] I  [DP] pdf(0) 1 android.view.ViewRootImpl.lambda$performDraw$1$ViewRootImpl:4681 android.view.-$$Lambda$ViewRootImpl$DJd0VUYJgsebcnSohO6h8zc_ONI.run:6 android.os.Handler.handleCallback:938 
ViewRootIm...hActivity] I  [DP] rdf()
ViewRootIm...hActivity] I  MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
FA                      D  Connected to remote service
InputMethodManager      D  prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@91aad0e[SplashActivity]
InputMethodManager      D  getNavigationBarColor() -855310
InputMethodManager      D  prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@91aad0e[SplashActivity]
InputMethodManager      D  getNavigationBarColor() -855310
InputMethodManager      V  Starting input: tba=com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
InputMethodManager      D  startInputInner - Id : 0
FA                      V  Processing queued up service tasks: 5
InputMethodManager      I  startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
InputTransport          D  Input channel constructed: 'ClientS', fd=103
InputMethodManager      D  prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@91aad0e[SplashActivity]
InputMethodManager      D  getNavigationBarColor() -855310
InputMethodManager      V  Starting input: tba=com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
InputMethodManager      D  startInputInner - Id : 0
SurfaceControl          D  hide : mNativeObject = 482352385760 - sc.mNativeObject = 482336783008 - Surface(name=Surface(name=af417b8 InputMethod)/@0xaae80f6 - animation-leash)/@0x21c4289
SurfaceControl          D  nativeSetFlags Done : Surface(name=Surface(name=af417b8 InputMethod)/@0xaae80f6 - animation-leash)/@0x21c4289
SurfaceControl          I  release : mNativeObject = 482336776576 - Surface(name=Surface(name=8232d1f NavigationBar0)/@0xf0c3e35 - animation-leash)/@0x144428e / android.view.-$$Lambda$Rl1VZmNJ0VZDLK0BAbaVGis0rrA.accept:2 android.view.InsetsSourceControl.release:170 android.view.InsetsSourceConsumer.setControl:202 android.view.InsetsController.onControlsChanged:833 
SurfaceControl          I  nativeRelease nativeObject s[482336776576]
SurfaceControl          I  nativeRelease nativeObject e[482336776576]
SurfaceControl          I  release : mNativeObject = 482336776192 - Surface(name=Surface(name=6b87b34 StatusBar)/@0xbef3f11 - animation-leash)/@0xe2bcaaf / android.view.-$$Lambda$Rl1VZmNJ0VZDLK0BAbaVGis0rrA.accept:2 android.view.InsetsSourceControl.release:170 android.view.InsetsSourceConsumer.setControl:202 android.view.InsetsController.onControlsChanged:833 
SurfaceControl          I  nativeRelease nativeObject s[482336776192]
SurfaceControl          I  nativeRelease nativeObject e[482336776192]
WindowManager           pid-4569                             E  win=Window{94acd5 u0 Splash Screen com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true win.mViewVisibility=0 caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5227 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5208 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5616 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.onAnimationFinished:332 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onAnimationFinished:6081 com.android.server.wm.-$$Lambda$dwJG8BAnLlvKNGuDY9U3-haNY4M.onAnimationFinished:2 com.android.server.wm.SurfaceAnimator.lambda$getFinishedCallback$0$SurfaceAnimator:112 
SurfaceControl          D  hide : mNativeObject = 482352386400 - sc.mNativeObject = 484881882624 - Surface(name=Surface(name=6b87b34 StatusBar)/@0xbef3f11 - animation-leash)/@0x8b03ec6
SurfaceControl          D  nativeSetFlags Done : Surface(name=Surface(name=6b87b34 StatusBar)/@0xbef3f11 - animation-leash)/@0x8b03ec6
SurfaceControl          D  hide : mNativeObject = 482352386400 - sc.mNativeObject = 484881882624 - Surface(name=Surface(name=6b87b34 StatusBar)/@0xbef3f11 - animation-leash)/@0x8b03ec6
SurfaceControl          D  nativeSetFlags Done : Surface(name=Surface(name=6b87b34 StatusBar)/@0xbef3f11 - animation-leash)/@0x8b03ec6
SurfaceControl          D  hide : mNativeObject = 482352386400 - sc.mNativeObject = 484881882624 - Surface(name=Surface(name=6b87b34 StatusBar)/@0xbef3f11 - animation-leash)/@0x8b03ec6
SurfaceControl          D  nativeSetFlags Done : Surface(name=Surface(name=6b87b34 StatusBar)/@0xbef3f11 - animation-leash)/@0x8b03ec6
SurfaceControl          D  hide : mNativeObject = 482352386400 - sc.mNativeObject = 484881882624 - Surface(name=Surface(name=6b87b34 StatusBar)/@0xbef3f11 - animation-leash)/@0x8b03ec6
SurfaceControl          D  nativeSetFlags Done : Surface(name=Surface(name=6b87b34 StatusBar)/@0xbef3f11 - animation-leash)/@0x8b03ec6
SurfaceControl          D  hide : mNativeObject = 482352386400 - sc.mNativeObject = 484881882624 - Surface(name=Surface(name=6b87b34 StatusBar)/@0xbef3f11 - animation-leash)/@0x8b03ec6
SurfaceControl          D  nativeSetFlags Done : Surface(name=Surface(name=6b87b34 StatusBar)/@0xbef3f11 - animation-leash)/@0x8b03ec6
SurfaceControl          I  release : mNativeObject = 484881882624 - Surface(name=Surface(name=6b87b34 StatusBar)/@0xbef3f11 - animation-leash)/@0x8b03ec6 / android.view.-$$Lambda$Rl1VZmNJ0VZDLK0BAbaVGis0rrA.accept:2 android.view.InsetsSourceControl.release:170 android.view.InsetsAnimationThreadControlRunner.releaseControls:119 android.view.InsetsAnimationThreadControlRunner.access$200:40 
SurfaceControl          I  nativeRelease nativeObject s[484881882624]
SurfaceControl          I  nativeRelease nativeObject e[484881882624]
System.out              I  (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
System.out              I  (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
okhttp.OkHttpClient     I  --> POST https://xxxxxxx/api/user/checkversion
okhttp.OkHttpClient     I  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
okhttp.OkHttpClient     I  Content-Length: 45
okhttp.OkHttpClient     I  sender=provider&device_type=android&version=5
okhttp.OkHttpClient     I  --> END POST (45-byte body)
TTT access_token        D  
okhttp.OkHttpClient     I  <-- 500 https://xxxxxxx/api/user/checkversion (184ms)
okhttp.OkHttpClient     I  content-length: 672
okhttp.OkHttpClient     I  content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
okhttp.OkHttpClient     I  date: Fri, 28 Jul 2023 13:15:39 GMT
okhttp.OkHttpClient     I  server: Apache
okhttp.OkHttpClient     I  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
okhttp.OkHttpClient     I  <html><head>
okhttp.OkHttpClient     I  <title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
okhttp.OkHttpClient     I  </head><body>
okhttp.OkHttpClient     I  <h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
okhttp.OkHttpClient     I  <p>The server encountered an internal error or
okhttp.OkHttpClient     I  misconfiguration and was unable to complete
okhttp.OkHttpClient     I  your request.</p>
okhttp.OkHttpClient     I  <p>Please contact the server administrator at 
okhttp.OkHttpClient     I   webmaster@xxxxxxx to inform them of the time this error occurred,
okhttp.OkHttpClient     I   and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>
okhttp.OkHttpClient     I  <p>More information about this error may be available
okhttp.OkHttpClient     I  in the server error log.</p>
okhttp.OkHttpClient     I  <p>Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error
okhttp.OkHttpClient     I  error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
okhttp.OkHttpClient     I  </body></html>
okhttp.OkHttpClient     I  <-- END HTTP (672-byte body)
System.err              W  org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
System.err              W   at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:112)
System.err              W   at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:169)
System.err              W   at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:182)
System.err              W   at com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user.base.BaseActivity.handleError(BaseActivity.java:384)
System.err              W   at com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user.ui.activity.splash.SplashActivity.onError(SplashActivity.java:191)
System.err              W   at com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user.ui.activity.splash.SplashPresenter$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.accept(Unknown Source:4)
System.err              W   at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onError(LambdaObserver.java:77)
System.err              W   at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.checkTerminated(ObservableObserveOn.java:281)
System.err              W   at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:172)
System.err              W   at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:255)
System.err              W   at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:119)
System.err              W   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
System.err              W   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
System.err              W   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
System.err              W   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8506)
System.err              W   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err              W   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
System.err              W   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
FA                      V  Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (32604) for package com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.user ----------------------------
```

Comment: Can you tell us which line is throwing this error?

Comment: i dont now witch line, its freeze with the splashscreen. dont go to the login page.

Comment: Can you provide the full error then?

Comment: i will try, it¨s a lot of code.

Comment: Thanks, Niklas! Which line is throwing this error?

Comment: i don´t now thats why i ask for help.

Comment: You can find that out from your stack trace. Take a look at your logs again and particularly search for lines containing `System.err`.